# How to apply a class attribute to an HTML string (not rendered on the document)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am am developing code for am automator to improve the project with several pages.

I have a `textarea` input where I can enter HTML and it shows me the HTML with the right structure.

**HTML:**

```
<textarea name="message">
<input type="text" value="TextTwo" id="texttwo"/>
<input type="text" value="DataOne" id="dataone"/>
<input type="text" value="NumberTwo" id="numbertwo"/>
<input type="text" value="TextOne" id="textone"/>
<input type="text" value="DataTwo" id="datatwo"/>
<input type="text" value="NumberOne" id="numberone"/>
</textarea>

<button>process</button>
```

**JS/JQuery:**

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var code = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    if ($('#output').length < 1) {
        $("body").append('<h2>Output</h2><textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>');
    }        



    $('#output').val(code);
});
```

I would like to apply classes following these rules:

- The input that has the word "**Text**" value in applying the **class = "text"**
- The input that has the word "**Data**" value in applying the **class = "data"**
- The input that has the word "**Number**" value in applying the **class = "number"**

An example of how the code would output in textarea

```
<input type="text" value="TextTwo" id="texttwo" class="text" />
<input type="text" value="DataOne" id="dataone" class="data" />
<input type="text" value="NumberTwo" id="numbertwo" class="number" />
<input type="text" value="TextOne" id="textone" class="text"/>
<input type="text" value="DataTwo" id="datatwo" class="data" />
<input type="text" value="NumberOne" id="numberone" class="number" />
```

**[DEMO CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/LC5y3/2/)**

What is a good approach to do this using JQuery?

Comment: Why have you put inputs inside a textarea?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Because the OP allows HTML to be directly entered -- possibly saved off to a database on the backend.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am am developing code for am automator to improve the project with several pages.

Comment: May I assume the html in the textarea is valid html at all times? If so, I could write something up pretty quick. Otherwise I'd have to do a little more thinking.

Comment: Problem is that because the elements are inside a textarea, they cant (AFAIK) be accessed by jquery. In your fiddle, `var code = $('textarea[name=message]').val();` is just a string (not html elements)

Comment: Yes ! @AdamMerrifield

Comment: @StephenMuecke And became the the variable `code` Object? Doing this could apply these rules right? Example: `var object = $(code)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that all the html in the textarea is valid, What we can do is just build the html into a div and then format the html with jQuery. After this is done just get the content and put it in the textarea.

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var code = $('textarea[name=message]').val(),
        $code = $('<div />').html(code),
        classes = {'Text': 'text', 'Data': 'data', 'Number': 'number'};

    if ($('#output').length < 1) {
        $("body").append('<h2>Output</h2><textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>');
    }

    $('input', $code).each(function(){
        var t = this,
            $t = $(this);

        for(key in classes){
            if(t.value.indexOf(key) > -1){
                $t.addClass(classes[key]);
                return;
            }
        }
    });

    $('#output').val($code.html());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LC5y3/4/

Answer (score 3):

I updated your fiddle and had this code working -- Can't give you a link since I don't actually have a fiddle account:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var code = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    // The best thing to do here is to turn that string of HTML into
    // DOM elements and let the browser do the work.

    var elms = jQuery.parseHTML(code);
    var result = "";

    // Now that we've processed the HTML into an array, work with it.
    for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
        var el = elms[i];
        if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
            // Great! We we have an 'input' element.
            var val = el.value;

            if (val.indexOf("Text") !== -1) {
                el.className = "text";
            }
            if (val.indexOf("Data") !== -1) {
                el.className = "data";
            }
            if (val.indexOf("Number") !== -1) {
                el.className = "number";
            }            
        }

        if (el.nodeType === 3) {
            // Handle text nodes
            result += el.nodeValue;
        } else {
          result += el.outerHTML;
        }        
    }


    if ($('#output').length < 1) {
        $("body").append('<h2>Output</h2><textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>');
    }        



    $('#output').val(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/Qh8bx/2/)***

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var code = $.parseHTML($('textarea[name=message]').val());
    console.log(code);
    var newCode = "";

    code = $.grep(code, function (n, i) {
        if (n.nodeValue) {
            return n.nodeValue.trim()
        } else {
            return (n.outerHTML && n.outerHTML.trim())
        }
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
        var element=$(code[i]);
        element.addClass(element.attr("type"));
        newCode += code[i].outerHTML;
    }
    console.log(newCode);
    console.log(code);


    if (!$('#output').length) {
        $("body").append('<h2>Output</h2><textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>');
    }




    $('#output').val(newCode);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute [contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CodingDawg/LC5y3/3/)

```
$('input[id*="text"]').addClass('text');
$('input[id*="number"]').addClass('number');
$('input[id*="data"]').addClass('data');
```

Comment: Need it to apply in the format inside a `textarea` same'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically build the elements:

`$('input').addClass('className').attr('value','number');`